# Wordpress - Display sub-categories in 2 columns

Tags: wordpress

Im using the below code to display list of subcategories:

```
<?php
if (is_category()) {
$this_category = get_category($cat);
}
if($this_category->category_parent)
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent."&echo=0"); else
$this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
if ($this_category) { ?>
<?php echo $this_category; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

How can I display subcategories in 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is giving you lots of content through those functions. They provide you lots of functions to use this content, but if you're stucked and no function matches your needs, feel free to create your own.

Here, try a var_dump() of your object $this_category, and look at the result.

Then, you should be able to use this content to display your categories the way you want.